# Castor postgresql database connection

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, castor

My task is to represent the query result from a postgresql database to an xml format in a Java web application, in respect of a predefined XSD format. I am using castor which support both API O/R and O/XML mapping.

I have created a very simple and small database with one table to test it. 
Below is my code.

```
Object class:Catalogue

package com.castor.tutorial;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Catalogue implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer Id;
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Database connection and add the mapping file: castor.db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE jdo-conf PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor JDO Configuration DTD Version 1.0//EN" "http://castor.org/jdo-conf.dtd">
<jdo-conf>
  <database name="castor1" engine="oracle">
      <data-source class-name="org.postgresql.PostgresqlDataSource">
           <param name="serverName" value="host" />
           <param name="portNumber" value="5432" />
           <param name="databaseName" value="castordb" />
           <param name="user" value="postgres" />
           <param name="password=" value="test" />
           <jndi name="java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb" />
        </data-source>

 <transaction-demarcation mode="global">
   <transaction-manager name="jndi" />
</transaction-demarcation>

  <mapping href="resources/com/mapping.xml"/>
  </database>
</jdo-conf>


    Mapping file: mapping.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE class PUBLIC "-//EXOLAB/Castor Mapping DTD Version 1.0//EN" "http://castor.exolab.org/mapping.dtd">

<class name="org.castor.tutorial.Catalogue">
    <map-to table ="catalogue"/>
    <field name="Id" type="integer">
        <sql name ="id" type="integer"/>
    </field>

    <field name="code" type="string">
        <sql name="CODE" type="varchar"/>
    </field>

    <field name="name" type="string">
        <sql name="NAME" type="varchar"/>
    </field>

</class>

Main test file: Main_test

package com.castor.tutorial;

import org.exolab.castor.jdo.Database;
import org.exolab.castor.jdo.JDOManager;
import org.exolab.castor.jdo.PersistenceException;
import org.exolab.castor.mapping.MappingException;



public class Main_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MappingException, PersistenceException {

    JDOManager jdo;
    Database db;

    JDOManager.loadConfiguration("src/main/resources/castor.db.xml");
    jdo = JDOManager.createInstance("castordb");

    Database db2 = jdo.getDatabase();

    db2.begin();

    db2.commit();
    db2.close();

}
}
```

When I try to run this main file as a Java Application, it's showing the below exception:

```
Okt 31, 2014 2:53:23 PM org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping setBaseURL
Information: src/main/resources is not a URL, trying to convert it to a file URL
Okt 31, 2014 2:53:23 PM org.exolab.castor.mapping.Mapping loadMapping
Information: Loading mapping descriptors from resources/com/mapping.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.castor.jdo.util.JDOConfAdapter.getTransactionManager(JDOConfAdapter.java:38)
    at org.castor.jdo.engine.DatabaseContext.initialize(DatabaseContext.java:161)
    at org.castor.jdo.engine.DatabaseRegistry.loadDatabase(DatabaseRegistry.java:195)
    at org.castor.jdo.engine.DatabaseRegistry.loadDatabase(DatabaseRegistry.java:124)
    at org.exolab.castor.jdo.JDOManager.loadConfiguration(JDOManager.java:362)
    at org.exolab.castor.jdo.JDOManager.loadConfiguration(JDOManager.java:339)
    at org.exolab.castor.jdo.JDOManager.loadConfiguration(JDOManager.java:418)
    at com.castor.tutorial.Main_test.main(Main_test.java:17
```

Comment: No idea about castor but there usually should be an empty constructor. Additionally, you use `engine=oracle` but as connection to PostgreSQL. I assume this is not related to the error but more of a "hint".